# Do we need a "x509" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The user for this question: [How to get server's ssl certificate in a human readable form?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104623/how-to-get-servers-ssl-certificate-in-a-human-readable-form) asked if someone could add the tag [x509] to which I replied "no I don't think we need it".

In [searching for it I only found 29 references to x509](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=x509), seemed a little unnecessary to me.

- Do others think we need this tag?
- Do others concur?

Comment: X509 tag is now empty; please synonymize it with certificates.

Answer (score 9):

> Do others think we need this tag?

For that questions I normally ask myself "Myself, what is [x509](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x509)?" and myself answers with a wikipedia dump:

> In cryptography, X.509 is an ITU-T standard for a **public key infrastructure** (PKI) and **Privilege Management Infrastructure** (PMI). X.509 specifies, amongst other things, standard formats for public key **certificates**, **certificate** revocation lists, attribute **certificates**, and a **certification** path validation algorithm.

Then, I look another posts/tags that already has what x509 means: "[cetificates](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=certificates)", "[PKI](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=pki)", "[PMI](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=pmi)", "[Privilege Management Infrastructure](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=Privilege+Management+Infrastructure)", "[public key infrastructure](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=public+key+infrastructure)", other related terms/tags. Now, is the proportion of related terms big enough that it will make it **difficult for answerers find the questions they want to answer**? No? Then we do not need a tag.

Remember that tags aren't there for the users asking questions but for the users to find questions they want/could answer ;). I do not think we have an important proportion of users that would like to answer those kinds of questions, so **NO, we do not need that tag.**

Comment: I concur. 1) I would expect anyone who knows what `x509` is wouldn't be asking the question in that question. 2) It is a bit too specific to be useful. 3) It's more relevant to the answer than it is the question.

Answer (score 5):

Technically, X.509 and certificates are not synonyms:

- X.509 covers not only certificates, but also certificate requests and certificate revocation lists.
- It would be possible to encode certificates in other formats.

At the level of this website, I don't see any distinction to be made between [x509](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x509) and [certificates](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/certificates). In practice nobody encodes certificates in anything other than X.509. If a question is specifically about certificate requests or certificate revocation, it can use a tag like [certi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/certi) or [crl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crl) in addition to [certificates](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/certificates). So I think that [x509](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x509) and [certificates](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/certificates) should be synonyms.

(Security.SE has separate tags, but even there I don't think it's warranted; [I've raised that on their meta](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/can-we-authoritatively-merge-certificates-and-x-509).)